# iOS png resources: Use multiple names for the same file

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have two nib files that use the same image, but I want to call the image nib_a_image.png when I reference it from nib a, and nib_b_image.png when I reference it from nib b.

The idea is that my designers could give me a new nib_a_image.png and only affect behavior of nib a.

But I don't want to increase the size of my app by including the image multiple times.

<strike>Would symlinks work?</strike> Sounds like symlinks would work. Not sure I love the idea.

Has anyone tried to do something like this?

Comment: If you could end up with two separate images later, why not simply use two now? Or simply use one and update the nib if needed in the future.

Comment: Have you tried it? It looks like they should work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18085036/2708650

Comment: @rmaddy As I mentioned, I don't want to increase the size of my binary by embedding the same png twice. But more than that, I semantically want to know both are using the same image.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I've tried using symlinks before, and other people on my team yelled at me. Maybe because of Xcode bugs when working with symlinks.