# My iOS app was rejected because of an invalid SYMLINK

Tags: ios, symlink, apptentive

I have an application that uses a static library and an extension. After I built it and uploaded to the Appstore I got an email with the following:

> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
> 'ApptentiveResources.bundle/ApptentiveResources.bundle' which resolves
> to a location
> '/Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-deobhgkhragul
> tfojmikyyibbvsx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/APPNAME/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/ApptentiveResources.bundle'
> that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink -
> Your package contains a symbolic link 'PlugIns/Share With
> APPNAME.appex/Share With APPNAME.appex' which resolves to a location
> '/Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-deobhgkhragultfojmikyyibbvsx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/APPNAME/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/Share
> With APPNAME.appex' that does not exist or is outside of the package.

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Since March 2014 apps using a well known symbolic link workaround will not pass to the review.

I assume you have used this workaround in your application.

The workaround is discussed in the answer to this link;

[Adding a Symbolic Link in the Application Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399864/adding-a-symbolic-link-in-the-application-bundle)

Comment: I didn't use this in my project. I just added the Apptentive library and made an extension, and the problem seems to be with the bundle from the library :ApptentiveResources.bundle and something from the extension: APPNAME.appex

Comment: Did you make sure to click the "Copy items if needed" checkbox when adding the library?

Comment: The library is represented as a subproject and I followed all the instructions correctly. The weird thing is that it says the same for the extension of the app. I have looked for this files in the build and they are at the right place.

Comment: You need to add ApptentiveConnect as your target dependency. It should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the invalid symlink and resubmit