# How to use Symbolic Links on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, symlink

I've been trying to use Symbolic Links in my swift app with no luck. Is there anything I might be missing or is this even possible to begin with?

Here is my sample code and I have been using FileKit plugin to create my symlink. I also tried it without a plugin but no luck.

I tried this first:

```
import FileKit

do {
   try Path(Bundle.main.bundlePath + "/wwww/assets").symlinkFile(to: "/assets")
   debugPrint("Success")
} catch {
   debugPrint("Failed")
}
```

I always get the `Failed` message.

I also made sure that the bundle paths are valid with this test:

```
debugPrint(Path(Bundle.main.bundlePath + "/wwww/assets").exists) //true
```

Can you guys give me any pointers?

Comment: The application bundle is *read-only.* You cannot create files, symlinks, or anything else in the application bundle at runtime.

Comment: Printing `error.localizedDescription` in the failure case should also give some clue.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399864/adding-a-symbolic-link-in-the-application-bundle to me.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... I did see the other question being posted while looking around but it wasn't clear if you can actually create a symlink in ios/swift/xcode. It makes sense now that you mention it that it wouldn't let you create one since it makes the device vunerable. 

Thanks!

Comment: The key part here is *in the app bundle*. You should be able to create them in other areas that you have write access to